# Vector iterator not incrementable while collision

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a pacman game watching tutorials. So when the ghost is in weak state and the pacman collides with the ghost i am getting the error Vector iterator not incrementable. Can anyone please solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
for (Ghost*ghost : m_ghosts)
{
    if (ghost->getCollisionBox().intersects(m_pcMan->getCollisionBox()))
    {
        if (ghost->isWeak())
        {
            m_ghosts.erase(std::find(m_ghosts.begin(), m_ghosts.end(),ghost));
            m_score += 100;
        }
        else                
            m_pcMan->die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't thou heard? *"Thou shall not cause iterator invalidation on a `std::vector` while iterating through it using a range-based for-loop"*

Comment: Create a vector and name it ghosts_to_disappear or something. Put the ghosts to disappear there (pointers to) and then remove them from m_ghosts.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: You used a *range-based for-loop*, but inside the *for-loop*, you still use `std::find` to find an iterator to the current element so that you delete, that's inefficient.

---

Your problem stems from the fact that, after you delete an element pointed to by an iterator, **all** iterators and references to that element and after becomes invalid. The range-based for-loop tries to eventually increment an invalid iterator which invokes Undefined Behavior. Luckily, your STL implementation has checked iterators, so you got some nice error message.

---

There are a variety of ways to go about this. Though you may want to consider your Data Structure... Game Devs have more advanced tricks for this sort of thing. Nonetheless, here is a trick, swap the current `ghost` with the last on the vector, then pop the last element.

```
auto iter = m_ghosts.begin();
auto End = m_ghosts.end();
while(iter != End)
{
    if (iter->getCollisionBox().intersects(m_pcMan->getCollisionBox()))
    {
        if (iter->isWeak())
        {
            if(iter != std::prev(End)){ //We want to prevent `std::swap(x,x)`
                 std::iter_swap(iter, std::prev(End));
                 End = m_ghost.erase(std::prev(End));
            }
            else{
                 iter = End = m_ghost.erase(std::prev(End));
            }
            m_score += 100;
        }
        else{
            ++iter;
            m_pcMan->die();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help guys. This worked for me :)

```
for (int i=0;i<m_ghosts.size();i++)
{
    Ghost* ghost = m_ghosts[i];

    if (ghost->getCollisionBox().intersects(m_pcMan->getCollisionBox()))
    {
        if (ghost->isWeak())
        {

            m_ghosts.erase(std::find(m_ghosts.begin(), m_ghosts.end(), ghost));

            m_score += 100;
        }
        else

            m_pcMan->die();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, it is grossly inefficient for a game. Your algorithm has a poor worst case... You are are not erasing at constant time. could erase at constant time by `m_ghosts.erase(m_ghosts.begin() + I)`... Though it still incurrs some hit of moving elements in the vector... See my answer for a trick